# React component pass a const string to another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that concatenates several strings into one string, which I declare as a const to use as a URL. How to I use this const in another component, which needs the URL to fetch data?

**Example of the code:**

URLconcatenate.js creates the const URLstring

```
const string01 = 'www.'
const string02 = 'apple';
const string03 = '.com'
const urlString = string01 + string02 + string03

//this validates the concatenation
console.log(urlString);

function URLconcatenate() {
    return (
        <div>
            {urlString}
        </div>
    )
}

export default URLconcatenate
```

Datafetch.js (needs to receive and use the const urlString

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import URLconcatenate from './URLconcatenate';

const Datafetch = () => {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(urlString)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setPrice([data]);
            });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            {price.map((thePrice) => (
                <p key={thePrice.c}>Today's price for AAPL is: ${thePrice.c}</p>
            ))
            }
        </div >

    );
};

export default Datafetch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to export your urlString

```
// URLconcatenate.js
export const urlString = string01 + string02 + string03


// Datafetch.js
import { urlString } from './URLconcatenate';
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comment was so helpful, it's hard to believe how many tutorials I read that overcomplicated this, and your simple solution was all I needed!